# Python requests not working while cURL works

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to automate backups in Adobe Experience Manager.
I can do it from jmx console and I got cURL from there when I called a function to start backup.
I tried running the same curl from the terminal on my laptop and it worked fine as well.
Next I tried to do the same thing in python using requests however I keep getting 404 error.
Here's the original curl:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST http://localhost:4502/system/console/jmx/com.adobe.granite:type\=Repository/op/startBackup/java.lang.String\?target\=backup_test.zip
```

This works fine. Here's my python code:

```
import requests

URL = "http://localhost:4502/system/console/jmx/com.adobe.granite:type\=Repository/op/startBackup/java.lang.String\?target\=backup_test.zip"

resp = requests.post(URL, auth=('admin', 'admin'))
print(resp.content)
```

When running the above I get this error:

```
b'<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>\n<title>Error 404 </title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>\n<
p>Problem accessing /system/console/jmx/com.adobe.granite:type%5C=Repository/op/startBackup/java.lang.String%5C. Reason:\n<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>\n<hr />\n</b
ody>\n</html>\n'
```

When using this instead of full url:

```
URL = "http://localhost:4502/system/console"
```

I get 200.

What could be wrong with this?

Comment: Remove the extra \ escape characters - no `\?` or `\=`

Comment: You're correct. I missed those completely. Post this and I will mark it as answer